# Guidelines for OnPrem Site Branding

Tags: custom-masterpage, branding, design

I have been given conflicting advice as to trying to stay out the box with composed looks, vs creation of more branded MasterPages. The former claimed as a recommendation so that customers can easily go from OnPrem to 365. I don't buy that given organisations want to create some form of branding identity on their SharePoint Sites, Intranet portals and so forth. Can anyone provide a reference to best practice guidelines around this? Surely having properly constructed MasterPages with corporate branding can port to 365 and don't result in loss of performance with page load times and usability etc?

Comment: The other point is that if you are customizing the master page, you aren't getting the features available to you when they hit your tenant. On-prem this isn't an issue. Vesa and the PnP group say you can and is supported in 2016, but they don't recommend it. There are other ways to achieve the things you might want, without modifying master pages.

Comment: Thanks Eric, are you able to expand on the alternative ways?

Comment: Not in much detail, these were generalities expressed by Vesa at Ignite. I can point you to the PnP github repo where they have a lot of samples, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP